# Swift generic protocol function with self

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a generic class that conforms to a delegate protocol. I want to be able to pass `self` in the protocol methods, but I can't figure out how.

```
protocol BodyPartManagerDelegate: class {
    func doit(manager: BodyPartManager<Any>)
}

class BodyPartManager<Part> {

    weak var delegate: BodyPartManagerDelegate?
    var parts: [Part] = []

}

class Neck {}

class NeckManager: BodyPartManager<Neck> {

    func doingit() {
        delegate?.doit(manager: self)
    }

}
```

With the code above, I get `protocol 'BodyPartManagerDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. How can I get access to `self` in the methods of this protocol?

Comment: Check about Type Erasure in Swift on google, the topic is quite wide

Comment: And what if you will make a parameter in the protocol as Any? I mean in this way: func doit(manager: Any?). Then you can unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a commonality between your generic class declarations in order to allow passing any of them to a single function.  This can be achieved by declaring yet another protocol that all your generic typed classes will support (e.g. in the base class).

Here's an example:

```
protocol BodyPartManagers {}  // <-- common protocol for all generic classes
protocol BodyPartManagerDelegate: class
{
   func doit(manager: BodyPartManagers)
}

extension BodyPartManagerDelegate
{
   func doit(manager: Self) {}
}

class BodyPartManager<Part>:BodyPartManagers // <-- this will make all generic classes compatible
{
    weak var delegate: BodyPartManagerDelegate?
    var parts: [Part] = []
}

class Neck {}

class NeckManager: BodyPartManager<Neck> 
{
    func doingit() {
        delegate?.doit(manager: self)
    }

}
```